# Correct GenServer implementation with persistent state

Tags: elixir, amqp, erlang-otp, gen-server

I am new to some OTP concepts. I have GenServer, that will Publish events to RabbitMQ. This GenServer has the state: `amqp Chanel` which is initiates once during init() and is persistent between `cast` invokes.

```
defmodule Myapp.Events.AmqpTransport do

  require Logger
  use GenServer
  use AMQP

  def start_link(_) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init(_opts) do
    username = get_conf(:username)
    password = get_conf(:password)
    host = get_conf(:host)
    port = get_conf(:port)
    vhost = String.replace(get_conf(:vhost), "/", "%2f")
    exchange = get_conf(:exchange)
    {:ok, conn} = Connection.open("amqp://#{username}:#{password}@#{host}:#{port}/#{vhost}")
    {:ok, chan} = Channel.open(conn)

    {:ok, chan}
  end

  def handle_cast({:emit, event}, chan) do
    payload = :jiffy.encode(%{event: event})
    Basic.publish(
      chan,
      get_conf(:exchange),
      get_conf(:routing_key),
      payload
    )
    {:noreply, :ok, chan}
  end

  def emit(event) do
    GenServer.cast(__MODULE__, {:emit, event})
  end

  defp get_conf(key) do
    conf = Application.get_env(:myapp_events, :rabbit)
    conf[key]
  end
end
```

When I call it using `Myapp.Events.AmqpTransport.emit(%{"hop": "hej"})` I get error:

```
[error] Supervisor 'Elixir.Myapp.Events.Supervisor' had child
        'Elixir.Myapp.Events.AmqpTransport' started with
        'Elixir.Myapp.Events.AmqpTransport':start_link([])
        at <0.7024.0> exit with reason timeout_value
        in gen_server:loop/7 line 437
        in context child_terminated
```

What I missed here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return two-element tuple `{:noreply, chan}`, not three-element tuple `{:noreply, :ok, chan}` from [`GenDerver.handle_cast/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html?#c:handle_cast/2).

Casts are async and hence they don’t return anything. Your three-element tuple `{:noreply, _, _}` is treated as a response in a form

```erlang
{:noreply, new_state,
    timeout() | :hibernate | {:continue, term()}}
```

and the `state`, passed as a third element, is expected to be a timeout (it does not match `:hibernate`, nor the tuple), but its value is not a timeout by any means.